# nrf_mesh_init/nrf_mesh_node_config causing MESH ASSERT

Tags: c++, bluetooth, nrf51

I am testing out the [Nordic Semi Bluetooth Mesh SDK 0.9.1 Alpha](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-low-energy/nRF5-SDK-for-Mesh) using the light control client/server example.

The examples source code has not been modified.

I have set up a nRF52 development kit as the client, and a nRF51 development kit as a server. After building and downloading the hex files to the boards, the On/Off LED just stays on and it hangs.

The debug window for the client shows:

```
<t:          0>, main.c,  318, ----- BLE Mesh Light Control Client Demo -----
<t:          0>, main.c,  108, Initializing softdevice
<t:          0>, nrf_mesh_sdk.c,  109, Initializing SoftDevice...
<t:          3>, nrf_mesh_sdk.c,  118, Ram base: 0x200022D8
<t:         23>, nrf_mesh_sdk.c,  123, sd_ble_enable: app_ram_base should be adjusted to 0x20001900
<t:         32>, main.c,  116, Initializing mesh stack
<t:        281>, nrf_mesh_sdk.c,   70, MESH ASSERT at 0x000234D2
```

Also the server hangs at the MESH ASSERT.

History: I was previously testing out the blinky app, as well as the HRM apps, and they both are working fine (so the SoftDevice is installed and is fine).

What could be wrong? How can I debug more?

Update: I just tried with the other example, namely pm_remote_server, and it didn't work either, same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had selected the wrong Active Build Configuration in Segger.

Plus, make sure to erase all before downloading to device.